# Move item from one Vector to another when both vectors are inside an enclosing Vector using Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I have a vector of vectors, and the number of vectors can change at runtime. I therefore have:

```rust
struct ItemStruct {
    old: usize,
    transfer: usize,
}

//...

let number_of_vectors = x.len();
let mut ListOfItems = vec![vec![0; 0]; number_of_vectors];
```

there is then some code to add to the internal vectors, which all goes fine.

However, later on I need to move items between vectors (inside one vector) and I always trip up from the ownership rules:

```rust
 for item in anotherList.iter() {
        let to_move = ListOfItems[item.old].rchunks(4).next().unwrap();
        ListOfItems[item.transfer].append(&mut to_move.to_owned())
    }
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `ListOfItems` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src\main.rs:53:9
   |
52 |         let to_move = ListOfItems[item.old].rchunks(4).next().unwrap();
   |                       ----------- immutable borrow occurs here
53 |         ListOfItems[item.transfer].append(&mut to_move.to_owned())
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here ----------------- immutable borrow later used here
```

How do I move an item from one vector to another? If I new the number of Vectors at compile time I would do it differently, but because its variable, I have gone with creating a vector of vectors. I know I could do this in C and in Python but I also understand why Rust doesn't like it!

Comment: Do you want to remove the last 4 elements from the `old` vec and move them to the `transfer` vec, or do you just want to copy them and still leave the ones in old?

Comment: @pitaJ Move them, so one vector gains the 4 elements and the other loses them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to modify two portions of a single slice of memory is using [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut)

```rust
// Always split between the two points
let (old, transfer): (&mut Vec<_>, &mut Vec<_>) = if item.old < item.transfer {
    let (left, right) = ListOfItems.split_at_mut(item.transfer);
    (&mut left[item.old], &mut right[0])
} else {
    let (left, right) = ListOfItems.split_at_mut(item.old);
    (&mut right[0], &mut left[item.transfer])
};

// rchunks isn't the right way to move the last 4 elements
// `to_owned` will copy them
// instead, we use `drain` and `extend`
let to_move = old.drain(old.len()-4..);
transfer.extend(to_move);
```

Comment: At first this didn't seem like the right answer, but I now understand what you're doing. You are splitting the main vector and getting references to each side of it, then performing the actions. Smart! 

Is there much overhead to the `split_at_mut`? Is it creating a copies of each partition of the vector or just getting a reference to a slice of it?

Comment: There is practically zero overhead - it's just creating references to each portion. And it's very likely that part will be optimized out. There is no copying involved.